# JApplet: setting the size of the frame

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I read that this is a tricky question because an applet is run in the browser. But I would like my applet window to always maintain the same size. (Right now working with Eclipse I can slide the size of the window.)

For the moment I only do this:

```
public class myJApplet extends JApplet{
  public void init() {
     this.setSize(800, 480);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to add a `this.setResizable(false)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the size of the applet in the HTML.  E.G.

```html
<html>
<body>
<applet code="myJApplet" width="800" height="480">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

The applet will still be resizable when the HTML is loaded in the AppletViewer, but that is not relevant to deployment.